# Regex conditional lookahead issue

Tags: regex

I have a conditional lookahead regex that tests to see if there is a number substring at the end of a string, and if so match for the numbers, and if not, match for another substring

The string in question: "H2K 101"

If just the lookahead is used, i.e. (?=\d{1,8}$)(\d{1,8}$), the lookahead succeeds, and "101" is found in capture group 1

When the lookahead is placed into a conditional, i.e. (?(?=\d{1,8}\z)(\d{1,8}\z)|([a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+)), the lookahead now fails, and the second pattern is used, matching "H2K", and a "2" is found in capture group 2.

If the test string has the "2" swapped for a letter, i.e. "HKK 101"
then the lookahead conditional works as expected, and the number "101" is once again found in capture group 1.

I've tested this in Regex101 and other PCRE engines, and all work the same, so clearly I'm missing something obvious about conditionals or the condition regex I'm using. Any insight greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use a conditional or a lookahead (it is redundant to test a subpattern and then to match exactly the same subpattern). `(?:(\d{1,8}\z)|([a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+))` (eventually without the non-capturing group) does the same thing.

Comment: In my opinion the idea of a lookaround is/was to exclude such a match from e.g. participating in a capture-group (or even from the entire matching value). In case one wants to capture something there is no lookaround needed since one can provide a capture group before or after another matching pattern. Also it was better if the OP had provided some varying input values each with the expected result/output.

Comment: What language are you using , I noticed you are using `\z` like it's a `\b`?

Comment: And what is the lookahead in `(?=\d{1,8}$)(\d{1,8}$)` good for when the pattern directly starts with the lookahead itself. How it is written it looks more like someone tried writing a lookbehind but accidentally used the wrong syntax.

Comment: Peter el al; Thanks for your thoughts. As for conditional or not; for brevity and clarity, the example given is an very oversimplified case of what I'm doing (or trying to do); I wanted to focus on the functioning of the regex conditional itself, and NOT how to craft the best regex for my given problem. sidenotes: was not trying to use a lookbehind; using PHP (PCRE); as for \z vs $, I was trying different terminators. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The look ahead starts at the *current position*, so initially it fails, and the alternative is used -- where it finds a match at the current position.

If you want the look ahead to succeed when still at the initial position, you need to allow for the intermediate characters to occur. Also, when the alternative kicks in, realise that there can follow a second match that still uses the look ahead, but now at a position where the look ahead is successful.

From what I understand, you are interested in one match only, not two consecutive matches (or more). So that means you should attempt to match the whole string, and capture the part of interest in a capture group. Also, the look ahead should be made to succeed when still at the initial position. This all means you need to inject several `.*`. There is no need for a conditional.

```
(?=.*\d{1,8}\z).*?(\d{1,8}\z)|([a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+).*
```

Note also that `(?=.*\d{1,8}\z)` succeeds if and only when `(?=.*\d\z)` succeeds, so you can simplify that:

```
(?=.*\d\z).*?(\d{1,8}\z)|([a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+).*
```

There are two capture groups. It there is a match, exactly one of the capture groups will have a non-empty matching content, which is the content you need.

Comment: Trincot - Thanks! That makes sense; lookaround is "failing" initially outside the conditional too; its initial failure from the starting position is "transparent" though outside conditional, so it appears to be functioning differently but is functioning the same.  I could have sworn I tried a .* in the conditional, but apparently not.  As for conditional or not; for brevity and clarity, the example given is an oversimplified case of what I'm doing; I wanted to focus on the functioning of the regex conditional itself, and NOT how to craft a regex for the given problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match a number of specific length at the end of the string, and if there is none, match something else.

There is no need for a conditional here. [Conditional patterns](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) are necessary to examine what to match next at the given position inside the string based either on a specific group match or a lookaround test. They are not useful when you want to give priority to a specific pattern.

Here, you can use a PCRE pattern based on the [`\K` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) like

```
.*?\K\d{1,8}\z|[a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+
```

Or, using capturing groups

```
(?|.*?(\d{1,8})\z|([a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+))
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/7uuSqm/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/7uuSqm/2).

*Details*:

- `.*?\K\d{1,8}$` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, then the match reset operator that discards the text matched so far, then one to eight digits at the end of string
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z]+[\d_-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]+`  - one or more letters, 1-8 digits, underscores or hyphens, and then one or more letters.

And

- `(?|` - start of the [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `(\d{1,8})` - Group 1: one to eight digits
  - `\z` - end of string
- `|` - or

  - `(` - Group 1 start:
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
  - `[\d_-]{1,8}` - one to eight digits, underscores, hyphens
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
  - `)` - Group 1 end
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to *branch reset group*.

Comment: @PeterSeliger You know, in the current regex, it is redundant. I will edit the answer to include two solutions.

Comment: I missed this response, but hopefully better late than never... would like to add my thanks for the "branch reset group" intro; I've been looking to be able to have two different patterns have the same capture group name...nice to finally know of an option